# Facebook Webhook not posting notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

I created an app in my face book account and i added a callback URL in the web hook. The verification part is success and I did the subscriptions to the topics which i need to get notifications.

I clicked the test button in each topic to send the object to my server, it is working good and i can see test response in my server. But when i get any like in my page it is not posting the notification to my server.

I subscribed to all the topics such as like, feed etc.

Do i missing something?

Comment: You need to subscribe your app to the specific page as well ...

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. How to subscribe my app to the specific page. Is there any documentation available?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks#permissions, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps#Creating